# get original template before replaced by the angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I get the original markup before getting replaced by angular js directives? This question has already been asked, but I am posting this as the solutions don't work for me and also I want to know if the angular js team may have introduced any new methods for this.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
  function $block($compile) {

    var html = '<div>new content</div>';

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: function(element, attrs) {
        console.log(element); // still getting the new element
        return html;
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           console.log(element)
      }
    };

  }

  angular.module('directive', [])
    .directive('myDirective', $block);
```

How can I get the old template and then replace it with the new one?

Answer (score 1):

When you `console.log` an object, the browser displays the content value at the time it is viewed. Not at the time it was logged. That is the way the Developer Console works.

If you log the `innerHTML` you will see that they are different:

```js
angular.module('directive', [])

    .directive('myDirective', $block);
 
  function $block($compile) {

    var html = '<div>new content</div>';

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: function(element, attrs) {
        console.log(element[0].innerHTML);
        return html;
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           console.log(element[0].innerHTML);
      }
    };

  }
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app=directive>
    <h1>Directive Demo</h1>
    <my-directive><div>Old Content</div>
    </my-directive>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  angular.module('directive', [])
    .directive('myDirective', function(){
      return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<div>new content</div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      },
      compile:function(scope,element){
      console.log(element.$$element[0].outerHTML)
      
      }
    };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body ng-app="directive">
<div style="background-color:red;" my-directive>Hello</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this also prints the new content only not the old one.

Comment: Instead of pasting a whole code, explain what it does.